# Why Tanstack.Query cancel my first query and refetch it?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, render, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I have a context to manage my queries. When user click 'update all data' button I add forceUpdate param to my query and it looks like adress?forceUpdate=uniqueValue.
But my query with forceUpdate kay canceled, I dont know why:(

This is how I update forceUpdate key:

```
const forceUpdateHandler = async () => {
    await queryClient.cancelQueries([QueryKeys.DATA_FROM], { exact: false })
    setForceUpdate(v4())
}
```

Here is a place, where I create context with forceUpdate value

```
<QueryParametersContextProvider
      forceUpdate={forceUpdate}
      startArgs={startArgs}
      value={{
        queryParameters: new Map(dashboardParams?.queryParameters),
        applyQueryParameter: (param) => applyParameters({ queryParameters: param }),
        removeQueryParameter: removeParameter,
        forceUpdate
      }}>
</QueryParametersContextProvider>
```

Here in I use my context and check diff between old forceUpdate value and new and change my parameters if it changed

```
export const useQueryParams = (paramsForObserve?: Partial<IHashParameter>[]): UseQueryParamsResult => {

*other code with other logic*
  const context = useContext(QueryParametersContext)

  const prevUpdate = useDeferredValue(context.forceUpdate)

  const parameters = useMemo<QueryParameters>(() => {
    const initQueryParams: QueryParameters = paramsForObserve?.some(p => p?.key === ReservedKeys.expanded) ?
      new Map([[ReservedKeys.expanded, fullScreen]]) :
      new Map()

    const observableParams = paramsForObserve?.reduce((prev, curr) => {
      return curr?.key !== ReservedKeys.expanded
        ? new Map(prev.set(curr?.key, context.queryParameters?.get(curr?.key)))
        : prev
    }, initQueryParams as QueryParameters)

    if (prevUpdate !== context.forceUpdate) {
      const baseParamsForUpdate = new Map(reservedParams.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.set(curr, context.queryParameters.get(curr)), initQueryParams))
      const result = new Map([...Array.from(baseParamsForUpdate), ...Array.from(observableParams ?? []), [ReservedKeys.forceUpdate, context.forceUpdate]])
      return result
    }

    return observableParams

  }, [context.queryParameters, paramsForObserve, context.forceUpdate, fullScreen])

  return [
    parameters, applyParameters, removeParameter, getParametersByKey
  ]
}
```

I tried to remove forceUpdate param - it doesnt work
Then I tried to check reasons, why query was canceled, but there are text "without reaseon"
Here is a place, where fetch data

```
const dataQueryKey = useMemo(() => [QueryKeys.DATA_FROM, object, view,
  ...parametersForHash?.map(({ key, value }) =>
    `${key}=${typeof value === 'object'
      ? JSON.stringify(value)
      : value}`)]
    , [parametersForHash])

  const dataQuery = useMemo(() => ({
    queryKey: dataQueryKey,
    queryFn: fetchDataFromSource(parameters)({ object, view }),
    ...defaultQueryConfig,
    enabled: (!loadingObservablegQP || !useQueryParameters) && !!object && enable,
    refetchOnMount: false,
    retryOnMount: false,
    refetchInterval: interval,
    refetchIntervalInBackground: true,
  }), [dataQueryKey, loadingObservablegQP, parametersForHash])


  const data = useQuery(dataQuery)
```

UPD1:
[image: network after click button 'update all data']

Comment: problem was the lack of memoization